# How to do local keymap with use-package

Tags: use-package

I want to bind the `verb` package's keymap within `org-mode`. Currently, I am using the `with-eval-after-load` function in the `:init` option.

```
(use-package org-plus-contrib
  :ensure t
  :init
  (require 'org-tempo)
  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") verb-command-map))
)
```

It seems there's a `:bind-keymap` option for this. But I just cannot get it to work. After I defined the `:bind-keymap` option, it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:map` keyword within the `:bind` section. like this:

```
(use-package org-plus-contrib
  :ensure t
  :init
  (require 'org-tempo)
  :bind (:map org-mode-map ("C-c C-r" . verb-command-map))
)
```